# Intellij Play make project error: not found: object Keys

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, Play 2.0.4

I got this error running Build...Make Project:

```
Scala: not found: object Keys
import Keys._
```

This is an existing Play 2.0.4 project which I typically run from Eclipse and command line using "sbt ..." instead of "play ...". I also use paul sbt-extras script
https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras

plugins.sbt has this line

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")
```

The error is in my Build.scala file which has the typical first few lines of a Play project like

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._
```

I think I need to specify Play configuration home and working directory but not sure what put in them.

Comment: If play works in the Terminal you can just run `play idea no-sbt-build-module` to create IDEA project files with all the dependencies configured automatically.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, `play` no longer runs in the terminal, only `sbt` works for me, `sbt idea no-sbt-build-module` says `not a valid command: no-sbt-build-module`. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Oops, forgot to quote arguments, tried `sbt "idea no-sbt-build-module"` but got new error `Expected 'no-sources' idea no-sbt-build-module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ran into the same issue, I had to do a few things.

Note: I am using `sbt version 0.11.3-2`

1) `plugins.sbt` changes

- added resolver: `"sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/",`
- added `sbt-idea` plugin: addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.1.0")
- downgraded Play plugin to `2.0.1`: addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.1")

2) `sbt gen-idea`

3) If you get this error

scala: Output path /Users/rngu/ij/admin-tools/project/target/scala_2.9.1 is shared between: Module 'admin-tools-build' production, Module 'admin-tools-build' tests
Currently external Scala compiler prohibits output path sharing.
Either disable the external build mode or configure separate output paths.
TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to combine compiled classes.

To fix this, IntelliJ…File…Project Structure… add `/classes` to `Output path`, `/test-classes` to `Test output path`.

4) `Build...Make Project` should work now.